# Problem with build of Android app from react native code

Tags: javascript, react-native, gradle

Hello Folks when I try to run the react native application, it shows me the error given below

- What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':@react-native-community_async-storage'. > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.    > org/gradle/api/plugins/MavenPlugin

Comment: react-native-community_async-storage has been deprecated. You can use @react-native-async-storage/async-storage instead.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.